# The itemrenderer problems with states and rollover event

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

I have been used a custom itemrenderer to build a program needed.

In the itemrenderer it looks like this.

i use  to deal with the calse effects when user move mouse over a specific item renderer.

```
<s:postLayoutTransformOffsets>
    <mx:TransformOffsets id="offsets" x.hovered="-10" y.hovered="-15" scaleX.hovered="1.2" scaleY.hovered="1.2" />
</s:postLayoutTransformOffsets>

<s:transitions>
    <mx:Transition fromState="normal" toState="hovered" autoReverse="true">
        <s:Animate target="{offsets}" duration="200">
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="scaleX" />
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="scaleY" />
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="x" />
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="y" />
        </s:Animate>
    </mx:Transition>
    <mx:Transition fromState="hovered" toState="normal" autoReverse="true">
        <s:Animate target="{offsets}" duration="200">
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="scaleX" />
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="scaleY" />
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="x" />
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="y" />
        </s:Animate>
    </mx:Transition>
</s:transitions>
```

After that is the script part deal with the event or logic with the renderers.

For each render there will have to buttons contained in the renderer and showed only when user move mouse on the renderer, each button can trigger a event to deal with.

the last part code is about the container in the renderer.
First is a  which have a "rollOver" and "rollOut" event, when user rollOver a button and click it the event will executed. same to the rollOut.
Inside the Group there is a image bound with the pictures that will be show in the renderer.
A Hgroup contains the button that with the Event to execute when user click on it.

The problem i have been meet is: 
1. the states is not controllable, when user move mouse over a render and do the click, other itemrenderer will do the scale as well. that the sates problem and i have override the getcurrentstates method to fix that,that works but 
2. after fix the itemrenderer states problems i found the other itemrender which is not clicked by users also can execute the rollOver event, which is pretty wired.

I'm not sure if this problem is also about the states of itemrenderer or it is about something else i don't have a idea.

Hope someone can help me find some clues and solutions , or maybe just suggestions that could be helpful.

cheers.

Comment: You could add one more state to handle this cases: hoveredAndClicked

Comment: tried that, and that works for the other render states is not correct, but after  manage the state there still have a problem: the other itemrenderer still can execute the rollOver event when i click on another render, that is problem that confuse me this moment .

Comment: After start from scratch build a new render i found the problem is caused by the event that dispatched when clicked on the button inside the button. after i block the event sentences it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the item renderers are being reused for other items in the list, and when being reused, they maintain the previous state they were.

You should set the state of the items to the default one if they are being reused. Do that by overriding the "set data" function, however you will have to disable the transitions, otherwise they would be played too.